# how to set the map options in gmap4rails latest vesion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I am using gmap4rails, my rails version is 4.

In earlier version we can use the map options like below:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => { "data" => @markers, "options" => { "randomize" => true, "width" => 22, "length" => 32 } }) %>
```

Below is my latest gmap4rails version code:

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="multi_markers" style='width: 520px; height: 350px;'></div>
</div>



<script>
  var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap(internal: {id: 'multi_markers'}}, function(){
    var markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @data.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });  
</script>
```

I want to display the multiple marker for one location. For that I want to add the map options "randomize and `max_random_distance`" in my gmap. How can I add this in my latest version of gmap4rails. Please help me out. Thanks in advance!!!.

Comment: I have fixed this issue by adding the below line in the gmap_google.js file

Changed the 
maxRandomDistance: 0 to
maxRandomDistance: 100,

and
added the 
randomize: true
Now the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to edit the source, you can pass params:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: 100 } });
```